# prevent POST-request from caching

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching, cordova

When I try to make a jquery ajax "Type:Post" request, I get an 404 not found (from cache) error. I've tried several workarounds to fix this problem but it doesn't worked. This are the workarounds I've tried:

1. Adding header information in ajax call:
   "Cache-Control" : "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
   "Expires" : "0",
2. jquery ajax "cache:false"
3. add rnd URL param, `"?nocache=' + new Date().getTime()",`
4. tried to disable AppCache (nativ):

"super.appView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);"

This is the response I get from this POST request when I debug my Cordova App with dev tools:
http://pl.vc/59s6o

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your browser or the server, not JQuery.

Comment: I developed this project as a Webapplication and as a Cordova project. The webapplication works fine with the same request I use in the Cordova project. I've tested it in chrome and Postman. The problem only apears in the Cordova project

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your headers in the `$.ajaxSetup`

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   type: 'POST',
   headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" }
});
```

We can help you more if you tell us more about your situation and include your code.

Comment: Thx for your reply. unfortunatly this doesn't work for me. When I debug with about:inspect (devTools) I get a 404 not Found (from cache).