# How to submit data using ajax and display result without refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

**EDIT:**
SOLVED. Thank you all for help. :)

---

**EDIT:**
Your suggestions worked. The problem now is that after the first find and displaying the found result, the found set stays the same no matter what i try to find next. Even after restarting the browser. Is it possible that the found data stays somewhere in server cache and is displayed as a result?

---

I'm trying to send data from the form using jquery to php file process it there and then display the result from it.

After pressing the submit nothing happens. There are no errors in the console.
Everything worked before i added jquery but after that i don't see any result.

My HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="my_form">
Imie: <br/> <input name="name" id="firstname" type="text" /><br />
<input id="submit_form" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="update_div"></div>

<script>
var submit_button = $('#submit_form');

submit_button.click(function() {
var var_name = $('firstname').val();
var update_div = $('#update_div');
console.log('zmienna var_name ' + var_name);
console.log('zmienna update_div ' + update_div);
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'test.php',
    data: var_name,   
    success: function(response){
       update_div.html(response);
    }
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My PHP:

```
<?php

require 'db_handler.php';

$criterion_name = $_GET['name'];

$query = $fm->newFindCommand("OFERTY tabela");
$query->addFindCriterion('kontrahent_opiekun', "=" . $criterion_name);
$result = $query->execute();

if(FileMaker::isError($result)){
echo($result->getMessage());
return;
}
$i = 0;
// Get array of found records
$records = $result->getRecords();
foreach ($records as $record) {
echo $record->getField('_kp_oferta') . " - ";
echo $record->getField('kontrahent_Skrot') . " - ";
echo $record->getField('kontrahent_opiekun') . '</br>';
$i++;
}
echo $i . " Pozycje";

?>
```

Comment: Have you checked your server's error logs?

Comment: `$('firstname').val();` should be: `$('#firstname').val();`

Comment: Good eyes @RainDev! I am voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Also your `data: var_name,` is not properly setup. It should be key value association. For example `data: {name: var_name}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23392529/1011527.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30654063/1011527